# How to set maxLength in CkEditor 5 in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

How to set maxLength in CKEditor in react js.

I need to set max length character of the ckeditor text area

Does anyone give some examples?

```
return <CKEditor
    data={data.substring(0, maxLength)}
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    config={editorConfiguration()}
    maxLength={10}>
```

Comment: Please post code, what you have tried.

Comment: @shubham-gupta, please check

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no settings to limit number or characters, but you can add custom plugin for it: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18032

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
                        maxLength="9"
                        name="phone_number"
                        type="number"
                        onInput = {(e) =>{
                            e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,9)
                          }} 
                        placeholder="მობ.ნომერი"
                        value={values.phone_number || ""}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
```

> use onInput cause maxLength doesn't work for number type